# Check if an input field contains something

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, input

I'm making a `create a name function`, and then you can click on enter to save your name. But if the input field (where you type your name) is empty, an empty name will be saved and that's not good :)

So I was wondering how to make an `if` statement to look if the input field in Unity contains something.
Or if it contains nothing, maybe someone have another solution!

To find my input field I created a gameobject an dragged the inputfield in it. and then `inputFieldText = inputFieldGame.GetComponent<Text>().text;`.

I am thankful for any help!

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` should help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make `inputFieldGame` of type `InputField`.

Secondly, dont get component of type `Text` on input field, because it has dedicated property.

Thirdly, to check the string for emptiness, use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` as mentioned in comments.

So the complete piece of code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NameCreatorOrWhatever
{
    public InputField inputFieldGame;

    public void CreateAName() 
    {
        string newName = inputFieldGame.text;
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newName)) 
        {
            // Name is not empty, so use it
        }
        else
        {
            // Name is empty
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, to check if the inputfield type of string is empty:

```
if(inputfield.text == "") 
{
   //your code
}
else 
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: Hello SaMat - Please add come meaningful context/theory around your answer. Code only answer are hard to understand.